# DSolve not returning a rule

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a PDE, but the `DSolve` is not returning a rule. How exactly can I get *Mathematica* to yield a solution?

```
pde = D[p[x, t], t] + (1 - 2*p[x, t])*D[p[x, t], x] == 0
soln = DSolve[pde, p[x, t], {x, t}]
```

Result:

> ```
> Solve[C[1][p[x, t], (-t + x + 2 t p[x, t])/(-1 + 2 p[x, t])] == 0, p[x, t]]
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Edit: Revised explanation, incorporating references to documentation.]*

The PDE is a quasilinear PDE similar to 
[Burgers' equation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveIntroductionToPDEs.html#539501524), whose solution, also similar to the OP's, is discussed in the tutorial 
[Linear and Quasi-Linear PDEs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveLinearAndQuasiLinearFirstOrderPDEs.html).  A first-order quasilinear PDE
$$a\,p_x+b\,p_t=c$$
is linear in the partial derivatives, although the coefficients $a=a(x,t,p)$ etc. may depend on $p$.  The so-called **general integral** is given by
$$F(\,u_1(x,t,p),\, u_2(x,t,p)\,) = 0\,,$$
where $u=u_1$, $u=u_2$ are functionally independent solutions to the PDE
$$a\,u_x+b\,u_t+c\,u_p=0 \quad\text{or}\quad (a,b,c) \cdot \nabla u=0$$
and $F$ is an arbitrary $C^1$ function.  I'm not sure how universal the term *general integral* is.  It does not always represent all possible solutions, so it should not be confused with the (most) general solution.

The general integral represents a set of solutions $p=p(x,t)$ to the quasilinear PDE as functions defined implicitly by a family of equations parametrized by $C^1$ function $F(u,v)$.  It seems to be too much to expect that the solution set can be described in the form $p = f(x, t, F)$, although it can be done if a solution $u=u_1$ can be found that is independent of $p$ (e.g., in the strictly linear, homogeneous case).

The vector field $(a,b,c)$ for the OP's `pde` is

```
abc = {1 - 2 p, 1, 0};
```

and the PDE for $u$ is given by

```
abc.D[u[x, t, p], {{x, t, p}}] == 0
```

We can verify that `u[x, t, p] = p` and `u[x, t, p] = (-t + x + 2 t p)/(-1 + 2 p)` are solutions, which shows that `DSolve` returned the general integral:

```
Simplify[abc.D[p, {{x, t, p}}] == 0 /. p -> p[x, t], pde]
Simplify[abc.D[(-t + x + 2 t p)/(-1 + 2 p), {{x, t, p}}] == 0 /. p -> p[x, t], pde]
(*
  True
  True
*)
```

The parameter `C[1]` in the output of `DSolve` represents the arbitrary $C^1$ function $F$.  We can obtain explicit solutions by substituting an explicit function.

Examples:

```
Block[{C},
 C[1] = Total@{##} &;      (* C[1][a_, b_] = a + b *)
 soln /. HoldPattern[p[x, t] -> e_] :> (p -> Function @@ {{x, t}, e})]
pde /. % // FullSimplify   (* check solutions *)
(*
  {{p -> Function[{x, t}, 1/4 (1 - 2 t - Sqrt[1 + 4 t + 4 t^2 - 8 x])]},
   {p -> Function[{x, t}, 1/4 (1 - 2 t + Sqrt[1 + 4 t + 4 t^2 - 8 x])]}}

  {True, True}
*)

Block[{C},
 C[1] = {##}.{##} &;       (* C[1][a_, b_] = a^2 + b^2 *)
 soln /. HoldPattern[p[x, t] -> e_] :> (p -> Function @@ {{x, t}, e})]
pde /. % // FullSimplify   (* check solutions *)
(*
  {{p -> Function[{x, t}, 1/4 - (I t)/2 - 1/4 Sqrt[1 + 4 I t - 4 t^2 - 8 I x]]},
   {p -> Function[{x, t}, 1/4 - (I t)/2 + 1/4 Sqrt[1 + 4 I t - 4 t^2 - 8 I x]]},
   {p -> Function[{x, t}, 1/4 + (I t)/2 - 1/4 Sqrt[1 - 4 I t - 4 t^2 + 8 I x]]},
   {p -> Function[{x, t}, 1/4 + (I t)/2 + 1/4 Sqrt[1 - 4 I t - 4 t^2 + 8 I x]]}}

  {True, True, True, True}
*)
```